# trigger ignoring recordtypeid

Tags: apex, trigger, record-type

Hi I have the below trigger which i am attempting to have fire on only one recordtype id, however no matter what conditons i put in it still completes all tasks regardless of rectype

what am i missing

thanks

```
trigger TaskStatusUpdate on Task (before insert)  {

    id Rectypeid = Schema.SObjectType.Task.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Marketo Task').getRecordTypeId();  

    Set<Id> OppIds = new Set<Id>();

    for(Lead l : [SELECT  IsConverted, ConvertedContactId, ConvertedOpportunityId, Id, Status FROM Lead where isConverted =true and convertedOpportunityId !=null limit 1]){
        if(l.isConverted == true && l.ConvertedOpportunityId!=null ){
            oppIds.add(l.ConvertedOpportunityId);    
        }
    }

    List<Task> TasksToUpdate = new List<Task>();

    for(Task t : [Select Id, Status, recordtypeid from Task where WhatId in :OppIds AND recordtypeid = :Rectypeid]){
        If(t.RecordTypeId == '01258000000O8Jk'){
            t.Status = 'Completed - Progressing';
            TasksToUpdate.add(t);
        }
        Else {
            Break;
        }
    }

    update TasksToUpdate;
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your provided code (some unnecessary `if` statements aside), though I am having trouble trying to understand how a `beforeInsert` trigger is appropriate here. Can you go into more detail about _what_ you're trying to accomplish and _when_ you want to do it?

Comment: simply to update the status of a task with a particular record type when the lead is converted

Comment: If you're trying to update a `Task` on a `Lead` conversion, why is your trigger on `Task` and not on `Lead`? How is the task created in the first place? Do you have any other triggers or workflow? I can't help you without getting more details.

Comment: Hi Derek, my assumption was that i could the information i needed from the converted lead and carry out the dml actions on the task itself. at the moment the tasks are created manually and there are no other workflows and triggers running, the trigger works and updated the status of the tasks however it is not limited to just the one record  type i am trying to update, it updates all tasks on the conversion regardless of record type thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure on the logic you are aiming for, but this (untested) structure at least ensures that the `Lead` query is on the relevant rows (rather than an arbitrary row) and avoids the penalty of adding two queries to every `Task` insert done in your org:

```
 trigger TaskStatusUpdate on Task (before insert)  {

    Id rectypeId = SObjectType.Task.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Marketo Task').getRecordTypeId();  

    Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (Task t : Trigger.new) {
        if (t.RecordTypeId == rectypeId) {
            if (t.WhatId != null && t.WhatId.getSobjectType() == Opportunity.SObjectType) {
                oppIds.add(t.WhatId);
            }
        }
    }

    if (oppIds.size() > 0) {
        Set<Id> convertedOppIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (Lead l : [
                select ConvertedOpportunityId
                from Lead
                where IsConverted = true
                and ConvertedOpportunityId in :oppIds
                ]) {
            convertedOppIds.add(l.ConvertedOpportunityId);
        }
        for (Task t : Trigger.new) {
            if (t.RecordTypeId == rectypeId && convertedOppIds.contains(t.WhatId)) {
                t.Status = 'Completed - Progressing';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Querying with `limit 1` and using `break` in a `for` loop are warning signs that the trigger will not handle the bulk case.

Comment: sorry no this is still completing all record type tasks

Comment: @andy Suggest you add debug to find out why e.g. perhaps all tasks default to "Marketo Task" or some other logic is doing the update.